# If statement in launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to cancel the creation of a node in the launch file if a value, which is entered by user in console, equals a certain value.
For instance

I am launching a file: roslaunch file attr1:='1' attr2:='2'

and in my launch file i want to do a check. the syntax in any other language would be :

```
if (attr1 == value){ cancel node};
```

problem is, in the launch file I tried to use a unless="$(arg attr1)" but it's not a bool because when i enter the value in the console, it is an int. So i realized the unless and if conditionals in the launch file are explicitly looking for a true or false, and that they can't do a comparison:

```
unless="$(arg attr1 == '1')"
```

did not work. any suggestions? Any syntax I can use launch file that would make this work?

THANKS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212297/if-statement-in-launch-file/) by [thailor3](https://answers.ros.org/users/22915/thailor3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2015-06-26**:
This question has already been asked at http://answers.ros.org/question/12756/roslaunch-if-condition/
BUT I'm wondering if (and very hopeful that) things have changed in Jade. See my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just not possible. The arg `attr1` has to evaluate to true or false. This post is related: http://answers.ros.org/question/12756/roslaunch-if-condition/

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2